# Writing test case for scala akka webservice

Tags: java, scala, rest, akka, mockito

My application is in scala using akka and consume web services. I want to write test case for same but not exactly understanding which tools and technique to use. I am new to scala.I am told to mock webservice calls using (mockito), pls guide any working example or some hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will request to look Resito - Inspired by Mockito. It will pretty easy to mocking web service [read more](https://github.com/mkotsur/restito)

You can create simple web Serivce that already consuming by scala application and point scala application to mock service and check how it behave.

here is all example : https://github.com/mkotsur/restito/tree/master/examples

Please let me know if you have any question.

Mockito is also good but it is more easy to use Resito as it will create stub server and other thing easily.

Comment: Thanks @Boston Star ..I am also using spray along with akka and scala for http calls..will it work in resito?

Comment: Yes 100% Keep in loop if you have problem doing that let me know. You could do with https and http.  by adding .secure to new Stub server

Comment: ..the scenario is my Akka actor's methoddoing some http call like  http://abc/work/page   and I need to test it. So do I mock the akka actor itself? ... my problem is where should I start?

Comment: Assuming you want to mock service and URL is  http://localhost:80/abc/work/page , You will create new stub and using Whenhttp you will define this

Comment: StubServer server = new StubServer(80).run()

Comment: whenHttp(server).match(get("abc/work/page")).then(ok(), contentType("application/json"),
                    stringContent("return json"));

Comment: There were example in github ..import that maven example and run. You will get it.